# forEach filtrando pelo parâmetro que foi passado

Tags: javascript, telerik

Estou tentando resolver um problema aqui. Acredito que seja fácil, porém não tenho tanta intimidade com o javascript ainda. Seguinte: tenho um array em Javascript que tem algumas informações que eu preciso, como nome e titulação (exemplo: João, Ensino Superior) Na primeira vez que eu chamo a tela, todos os dados são carregados e preenchidos dentro desse array. Porém quando eu clico em um botão com uma determinada titulação, ele precisa carregar todos os professores que contém essa mesma titulação e montar uma grid.
O que eu preciso, basicamente é fazer um foreach e filtrar todos os professores que contém aquela determinada titulação.
Segue abaixo a estrutura da function:

```
function carregarDadosJ(titulacao) {
    var dataSource = data.forEach(titulacao);

    $("#divDadosDocentes").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        selectable: true,
        change: onChange,
        height: 750,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "Nome",
            title: "Nome",
            width: 200
        }]
    });
};
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo da estrutura de dados de `data`? É objet? array? E `titulacao` é uma string?

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que `titulacao` seja uma string, e `data` seja uma array de objetos, você consegue filtrar a array utilizando o método `.filter()` da array, assim:

```
function carregarDadosJ(titulacao) {
    // O método filter itera entre os itens da array e 
    // para cada um dos itens, a função passada será executada.
    // O filter retorna uma array com os itens os quais,
    // quando passado para a função, retorna true.
    var dataSource = data.filter(function (item, index, list) {
        // item  -> item da array
        // index -> indice do item na array
        // list  -> a própria array

        // Aqui deve ser executado o seu critério de filtro
        return item.titulacao === titulacao;
    });

    $("#divDadosDocentes").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        selectable: true,
        change: onChange,
        height: 750,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "Nome",
            title: "Nome",
            width: 200
        }]
    });
};
```

Importante lembrar que a array original não será mutada, o filter retorna uma array nova com os itens filtrados.

#### Compatibilidade

A compatibilidade dos métodos `filter`, `foreach` e demais, especificados na versão 5 do ecmascript, não são compatíveis com  navegadores antigos e IE < 9. Caso precise dessa compatibilidade, utilize o [lodash](https://lodash.com/), que muda praticamente nada da síntaxe:

```
var dataSource = _.filter(data, function (item, index, list) { ... });
```